# trying Camera in Rviz, transform?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

There are videos on youtube  where people manually moving the camera, and use Rviz to visualize the pointscloud, images etc. But to view the pointscloud 2, Rviz acutally requires transform of `/map to /[name of the camera_frame]`

I do have a camera working. I am wondering how should I archeive such requirement?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67055/trying-camera-in-rviz,-transform?/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to have your camera localized with respect to the world. `/map` is the conventional frame name associated with the world. You need a SLAM node (or whatever that can localize the position of the camera in the world) that will publish the transform from `/map` to `/your_camera_frame`.

I suggest you have a look at [rgbdslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam), that will probably help you obtain what you want with very little effort.

---

Originally posted by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) with karma: 411 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0